# simple deserialisation in .net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a simple string in JSON format returned like this.

```
{"access_token": "12345678901234567890", "token_type": "bearer"}
```

this is in string ResponseFromServer

I want to extract the two values from the sting, I don't want to go to the bother of setting up classes etc.

I have tried this

```
var BearerToken = new[] { new { acccess_token = "", token_type = "" } };
var myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(ResponseFromServer, BearerToken);
```

But its not working, any ideas for something simple?

Comment: Define "not working".  What happens?

Comment: Take away the new[]. Just have it be new { acccess_token = "", token_type = "" }  . Also, is there a reason it needs to be anonymous?

Comment: @ChrisKnight: The plural `myObjects` indicates that he does want an array, in this instance with a single element.

Comment: Then his JSON needs to be changed to indicate a collection with one item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have, is that here

```
var BearerToken = new[] { new { acccess_token = "", token_type = "" } };
```

you declare `BearerToken` as an array of anonymous types, while at json you have one object. Moreover, note the spelling error: in json you have `access_token` while at type declaration you have `acccess_token`.

For simplicity, you can use dynamic features of C#

```
var str = "{\"access_token\": \"12345678901234567890\", \"token_type\": \"bearer\"}";

dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);

Console.WriteLine(myObject.access_token); //prints 12345678901234567890
Console.WriteLine(myObject.token_type); //prints bearer
```

The working example of using anonymous type (note, that you got `BearerToken` declaration wrong, you have one object at json, not an array) is shown below:

```
var ResponseFromServer = "{\"access_token\": \"12345678901234567890\", \"token_type\": \"bearer\"}";

var BearerToken = new { access_token = "", token_type = "" };

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(ResponseFromServer, BearerToken);

Console.WriteLine(myObject.access_token); //prints 12345678901234567890
Console.WriteLine(myObject.token_type); //prints bearer
```

[working example for parsing with anonymous type](http://dotnetfiddle.net/WFDYOB)

[working example for parsing with dynamic binding](http://dotnetfiddle.net/cEkFHp)

If you are sure, that you need to have an array of object, then you need to wrap your json into square brackets `[]`. This would indicate, that you have an array of items. Then after fixing a spelling error, you can print values of the first item in that array:

```
Console.WriteLine(myObjects[0].access_token);
Console.WriteLine(myObjects[0].token_type);
```

Comment: thanks, just wondering if I can also check easily for correct Json fomratting so that I dont get a run time error if the kson isn't as I expected.